# ARM Kubernetes V1.11.2 HA cluster CoreDNS does not create pods

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi3, high-availability, coredns

In order to understand a bit more about cloud technologies I'm trying to create a Kubernetes High Availability Cluster using 6 Raspberry Pi 3's. The goal is 3 stacked masters and 3 workers.

I've followed the instructions at: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/ but whenever I include:

```
api:
  controlPlaneEndpoint: "master"
```

in the kubeadm-config.yaml I end up in a situation where CoreDNS services aren't deployed:

```
root@master-1:~# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                               READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   etcd-master-1                      1/1       Running   0          39m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-master-1            1/1       Running   0          39m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-master-1   1/1       Running   0          39m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-master-1            1/1       Running   0          38m
```

The deployment is installed, but for some reason it's not activated when I use the controlPlaneEndpoint directive.

```
root@master-1:~# kubectl get deployments -n kube-system
NAME      DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
coredns   2         0         0            0           41m
```

It's like it's not even trying.

If I exclude the controlPlaneEndpoint directive from kubeadm-conf.yaml its deployed correctly but then I cannot add the other masters without errors from kube-controller-manager and kube-scheduler

```
root@master-1:~# kubectl logs -n kube-system kube-controller-manager-master-2
invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided
root@master-1:~# kubectl logs -n kube-system kube-scheduler-master-2
invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided
```

I would expect CoreDNS to become 'Pending' until a CNI plugin has been installed.

This is driving me nuts. It feels like it's so close to working!

Any pointers are welcome.

Thanks,

// Fredrik

Comment: According to the instruction you provided, `controlPlaneEndpoint` should be with port, not only with name of the host. Here is the example, `controlPlaneEndpoint: "LOAD_BALANCER_DNS:LOAD_BALANCER_PORT"`

Comment: Thanks for replying. In this case it doesnt matter since if the LOAD_BALANCER_PORT is missing it will use the api.bindPort attribute. The biggest difference is that when I run kubeadm init, there will be no warning that the api.bindPort is overridden by the api.controlPointEndpoint value.


Regards,
// Fredrik

Comment: Does it help to add `LOAD_BALANCER_PORT` manually?

Comment: How do you mean? If I add it to the configuration file, the only difference is that I get warnings about api.bindPort being overridden. I have also tried different port numbers with no result. Thanks.